# can't install libpulse-dev in Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

i'm currently trying to build a docker container and install inside some library i'll be using for machine learning. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine


ENV PATH :$PATH

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

#Install dependencies
RUN echo "===> Installing sudo to emulate normal OS behavior..."
RUN apk --update add sudo
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
RUN apk --update add python py-pip openssl ca-certificates
RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies python3-dev libffi-
dev openssl-dev build-base gfortran
RUN apk --update add libpulse-dev
RUN apk --update add py-pip jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk --update add  swig
RUN apk --update add sshpass openssh-client rsync

#Install python package + requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN  pip install  -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "import_emails.py"]
```

i got some issue with libpulse-dev, which i need to have in order to install the Pockersphinx lib here's my TraceBack:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  43.12MB
Step 1/17 : FROM python:3.6-alpine
 ---> a6beab4fa70b
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3ad8815438e3
Step 3/17 : ENV PATH :$PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5b193bb0782c
Step 4/17 : ADD . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d68569825af4
Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eb6cad48bc0d
Step 6/17 : RUN echo "===> Installing sudo to emulate normal OS 
behavior..."
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cd3b9a162fdd
Step 7/17 : RUN apk --update add sudo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29c02ac6379d
Step 8/17 : RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 484e19727ba8
Step 9/17 : RUN apk --update add python py-pip openssl ca-certificates
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4f8b2f211bbe
Step 10/17 : RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies 
python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev build-base gfortran
 ---> Using cache
 ---> acffb3024164
Step 11/17 : RUN apk --update add libpulse-dev
 ---> Running in 2f381aef57d1
fetch http://dl-
cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-
cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libpulse-dev (missing):
    required by: world[libpulse-dev]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --update add libpulse-dev' returned a non-
zero code: 1
```

Any idea how to resolve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pulseaudio-dev to replace libpulse-dev

`RUN apk --update add`

Comment: While this command may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your suggestion.